# run ansible playbook with both --ask-pass and --ask-become-pass

Tags: ansible

I need to run a playbook on a remote host and I need it to ask me the ssh password and the sudo account password

- user1 is the ssh user
- user2 is the account with sudo

on remote host

```
user2 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

on controller

```
$ ansible-playbook -i hosts -l rhel8 create.yml --ask-become-pass --ask-pass
SSH password: (user1 password typed)
BECOME password[defaults to SSH password]: (user2 password typed)

PLAY [all] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Creating an empty file] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [rhel8]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {"discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/libexec/platform-python"}, "changed": false, "msg": "Error, could not touch target: [Errno 13] Permission denied: b'/root/file2'", "path": "/root/file2"}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
rhel8                      : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

playbook is

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: Creating an empty file
    file:
      path: "/root/file2"
      state: touch
...
```

I can ssh remotely

```
[user1@controller ~] $ ssh rhel8
user1@rhel8's password: (user1 password provided)
[user1@rhel8 ~]$

[user1@rhel8 ~]$ su - user2
Password: (user2 password provided)
Last login: Tue Mar 21 17:16:47 CET 2023 on pts/1
[user2@rhel8 ~] $

[user2@rhel8 ~] $ sudo touch /root/file
file created
```

now ay to works on ansible.
ansible is 2.9
Thanks for help

Comment: `--ask-become-pass` simply asks for the pass, wether you need it or not. It does not turn on become. So you should either use become on the command line (`-b`) or add `become: true` to your task specifically of the entire play if relevant. See [privilege escalation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_privilege_escalation.html)

Comment: Ah yes, that'll probably be the bottleneck, I pretty much always put that in my playbooks, so I wasn't even thinking about that. You should probably add this as an answer, @Zeitounator :)

Comment: I actually voted to close as caused by a typo.

Comment: even with -b (or --become) doesn't work 

[user1@controller ~] $ ansible-playbook -i hosts -l rhel8 create.yml --ask-become-pass --ask-pass -b
SSH password:
BECOME password[defaults to SSH password]:

PLAY [all] ************

TASK [Creating an empty file] *****
fatal: [rhel8]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Incorrect sudo password"}

PLAY RECAP ******
rhel8                      : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

Answer (score 0):

Please note that

```
su - user2
```

Doesn't use sudo, it uses su. And

```
sudo touch /root/file
```

Doesn't use `user2` but `root`, the default sudo user, since you haven't specified any user.

Try

```
sudo -u user2 touch /root/file
```

And see what it says.

Answer (score 0):

```
[user1@rhel8 ~]$ sudo -u user2 touch /root/file

[sudo] password for user1:

touch: cannot touch '/root/file': Permission denied
```

Instead:

```
sudo -u root touch /root/file2
```

works

but for security reason my company asked me to use user2 as admin user within sudo

Comment: Then ask your company to set up the appropriate permissions for user2, because clearly, it doesn't have the permissions needed. Or use a folder other than `/root`, which you shouldn't be using for anything, especially in Ansible playbooks, really.

Comment: user2 has got all the permissions.   

[root@rhel8 ~] # cat /etc/sudoers.d/ansible

user2 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL